# Как реализовать scrollbar в элементе chart

Tags: c#

У меня есть график на который я вывожу данные из файла. В файле содержаться даты и значения. Я хочу на графике получать максимум 15 значений, а все остальные значения будут за пределом графика и чтобы их увидеть надо будет переместить ползунок. Как это реализовать?

```
    public void openclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
     {
       OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
         chart1.Series[0].Points.Clear();
         txt = openFileDialog.FileName;
         string[] graf = File.ReadAllLines(txt);
         for (int i = 0; i < graf.Length - 1; i += 2)
             chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(graf[i], graf[i + 1]);
          // Set automatic zooming
          chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
          // Set automatic scrolling 
          chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
          chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
          chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScrollBar.Enabled = true;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Положить контрол в `Panel`, у панели есть скроллбары.

Comment: @aepot, А есть пример? Просто, я положил график на панель, включил скроллбар, но он не отображается. Да и смысл в этом ползунке если элемент chart будет сохранять свой масштаб невзирая на количество данных?